# Read variable that has space character in its value

Tags: bash, unix, scripting, escaping, whitespace

I have some paths stored in a variable (variable name -> test)

```
echo "${test}"
```

Result:

```
/abc/pqr/filepath1
/abc/pqr/lmn/file path2
/abc/pqr/rst/filepath3
```

I want to escape "space" character in the second path and get the owner for each path, I'm using following command:

```
stat -c '%U' ${test}   , works for 1st and 3rd path.
```

How do I make this work for the 2nd path? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have all the paths in a single string in a variable?  This seems like it might be a better place to use an array

Comment: How are you getting these paths in `$test`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `while` construct to get each filename, one per line:

```
while IFS= read -r f; do stat -c '%U' "$f"; done <<<"$test"
```

**Example:**

```
$ echo "$test"
/abc/pqr/filepath1
/abc/pqr/lmn/file path2
/abc/pqr/rst/filepath3

$ while IFS= read -r f; do echo "$f"; done <<<"$test"
/abc/pqr/filepath1
/abc/pqr/lmn/file path2
/abc/pqr/rst/filepath3
```

Comment: But the name is `file path2`, not `filepath2`.

Comment: @BenjaminW. It's not clear to me yet though, if thats the case then it would be easier, no need for the space removal. Edited.

Comment: It's pretty clear that the OP has file names that contain spaces (he wants to escape them, not delete them, so that the call to `stat` works).

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I need to retain the space character in the second path and your while statement works. However, the result I want is something like this:

while IFS= read -r f; do echo "$(stat -c '%U' $f)"; done <<<"$test"

which is still not working for the one that has space in the name

Comment: @Macopare Using `echo` and command substitution would get you same result. Anyway, if you insist, just quote the variable `f`: `while IFS= read -r f; do echo "$(stat -c '%U' "$f")"; done <<<"$test"`